# External, Fixed Background Image not showing

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML and I've been stuck at this for hours.

The picture just won't show up.

```css
.background {
  background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8153/7297534158_55171c3bf1_b.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Preptechies: The Wiki</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Welcome to our <strong>Webpage</strong>!!</h1>
      <h2>This is our group members</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="background">

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I took the CSS from W3Schools because I want to make the image fit the whole background and won't repeat & move when I'm scrolling the browser.

Comment: Put quotes around your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `.background` doesn't have a height.

Yes, you have `height: 100%`, but this is relative to `.wrapper` which doesn't have a height.

Add: `html, body, .wrapper {  height: 100%  }` to fix this.

```css
.background{
    background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8153/7297534158_55171c3bf1_b.jpg);
    height: 100%;

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

html, body, .wrapper {  height: 100%  }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Preptechies: The Wiki</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Welcome to our <strong>Webpage</strong>!!</h1>
      <h2>This is our group members</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="background">

    </div>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! i have not yet truly understand the concept but i think im getting there.

Comment: Hey @mafiq1102! No problem, it took me a while to get it as well. God bless!